# Can a convergent sequence exist such that the limit of the sequence is not a fixed point of the sequence rule?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fixed-point-theorems

Can a sequence defined by $$x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$$ exist such that it converges to $x$ but $$f(x)\ne x,$$ that is, $x$ is not a fixed point of $f$?

Motivated by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2133909/prove-that-this-iteration-cuts-a-rational-number-in-two-irrationals-sum-n-0). I wrote an answer there but something seems fishy and I cannot pinpoint what.

I see that it is obvious if you define the function pathologically (say $f(x) = (x+2/x)/2$ for real $x$ but $f(x)=0$ for imaginary x), so feel free to assume any "nice" properties for the function.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x_n)=f(\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x_n)=f(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Take $f(x) = \frac{x}{2}$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(x) =1$ for $x = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ is continuous at $x$, then
$$
x=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x_n)
$$
by the definition of $x_n$.  Since $f$ is continuous, we can interchange the limit and the function so that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x_n)=f\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n\right)=f(x).
$$
Therefore, you're looking for a function which is not continuous at $x$ in order to have the property that you're looking for.

Note that you can construct examples where the desired property holds, but $f$ is not continuous, so the precise requirements are hard to state.

An interesting related question might be if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=x$ such that $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$, can we find a *continuous* function $g$ that agrees with $f$ on $\{x_n\}$.